# How can I configure a fax server?

Tags: fax

I would like to use an Ubuntu 11.10 workstation as a fax server.  What would be the best application to use?  How do I configure it to act as both a fax server and fax client?  I've tried efax-gtk, but keep running into issues.  It mostly seems that the program cannot communicate with the modem.  I've tried 3 different internal modems.  Do I have to use an external modem via a serial port/com port?

Answer (score 2):

[HylaFAX](http://www.hylafax.org/) is in the repos and they also have a [hardware compatibility list](http://www.hylafax.org/content/Hardware_Compatibility_List) which might be a good start.

There are also a couple of tools that were created to provide a GUI for HylaFAX:

- http://www.downv.com/Linux/download-Hylafax-Panel-10003413.htm
- http://www.downv.com/Linux/download-gnu-hylafax-10001617.htm

Source: [Faxserver with GUI or web based interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507501/faxserver-with-gui-or-web-based-interface#comment684880_507501)

"WinModems" are unlikely to give you any real joy so if you can find a "real" modem (as listed) that should work. Finding one of those might solve your problems with efax.

Edit: Or throw the modems away and use an email->fax service instead.

Comment: +1 for the edit comment. When someone asks me to fax something I usually ask if I can send it by telegraph or telegram instead. They usually get the point.